# Debian jessie to stretch upgrade problem - "systemd breaks udev'"

Tags: debian, apt, upgrade, dist-upgrade

I've been trying to upgrade my current Debian Jessie to Stretch.

Unfortunately, at `apt-get dist-upgrade` failed, it returns:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 systemd : Breaks: udev (< 228-5)
           Recommends: libpam-systemd but it is not installed
           Breaks: udev:i386 (< 228-5)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Also, suggested `apt --fix-broken install` fails:

```
Do you want to continue? [T/n] t
Reading changelogs... Done
(Reading database ... 188728 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../archives/udev_232-15_amd64.deb ...
Since release 198, udev requires support for the following features in
the running kernel:

- inotify(2)            (CONFIG_INOTIFY_USER)
- signalfd(2)           (CONFIG_SIGNALFD)
- accept4(2)
- open_by_handle_at(2)  (CONFIG_FHANDLE)
- timerfd_create(2)     (CONFIG_TIMERFD)
- epoll_create(2)       (CONFIG_EPOLL)
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/udev_232-15_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
insserv: warning: script 'K01jira' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'jira' missing LSB tags and overrides
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
insserv: warning: script 'K01jira' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'jira' missing LSB tags and overrides
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/udev_232-15_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I guess Stretch requires newer kernel, than current:

```
~# uname -r
3.2.13-grsec-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64
```

but trying to install new `linux-image-*` fails because of `udev` and `systemd` issues.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is that an OVH kernel? You should check the available kernels there...

Comment: Yup, it's an OVH kernel, but not on OVH server anymore.

Comment: Could you try installing the latest Jessie kernel?

Comment: The steps here worked for me: [https://askubuntu.com/questions/146150/unable-to-fix-broken-packages-with-sudo-apt-get-install-f](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146150/unable-to-fix-broken-packages-with-sudo-apt-get-install-f) =)